# What packages are required to install vim on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, vim, rpm

What RPM packages are required to install vim on a recent version of Fedora?

Comment: I use Fedora 14 and vim already came installed with it. Strange that you didn't get it pre-installed.

Comment: I am using a custom version of Fedora, which is why the package is not on there by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a modern Fedora, run

```
repoquery  --tree-requires vim-minimal
```

or

```
repoquery  --tree-requires vim-enhanced
```

to get a recursive list of packages on which your specified package depends, in a nice tree format.

Note that vim-minimal only installs /bin/vi with no modern enhancements nor online help, for use when only the root partition is available. I guess you want vim-enhanced or vim-X11.

If you only want a list of the direct dependencies, you could run

```
repoquery --requires --resolve vim-enhanced
```

to get the packages list or

```
repoquery --requires vim-enhanced
```

to get the required capabilities.

Comment: And of course if you don't have `repoquery`, run `yum install yum-utils`.